# how to install google play services on genymotion in windows 10

Tags: android, genymotion

I am using windows 10, android studio 1.5.1

I started Genymotion and from google one of the user say to drag and drop the file Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip to the emulator. A dialog will appear and show as file transfer in progress, then another dialog will appear and ask that do you want to flash it on the emulator. Click OK and reboot the device by running adb reboot from your terminal or command prompt.

I am using windows 10 and I am not getting the above message so I try manual install:
I unziped Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip to folder "c:\test5\temp2" and I try the following command:

C:>adb push "C:\TEST5\temp2\system" /system
push: C:\TEST5\temp2\system/lib/arm/linker -> /system/lib/arm/linker
failed to copy 'C:\TEST5\temp2\system/lib/arm/linker' to '/system/lib/arm/linker': Read-only file system
2787 KB/s (71268 bytes in 0.024s)

I am running the above command in android studio terminal screen.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Genymotion on Windwos 10 myself.

1. Start Genymotion always as administrator
2. You can only drag & drop from other applications started as administrator

Comment: I run Genymotion as an administrator in windows 10 but when I dragged the Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip  file to the Genymotion Samsung 6 emulator nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong.